# pdf2img in node js giving a error 'identify' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js

```
var fs      = require('fs');
var pdf2img = require('pdf2img');

var input   = __dirname+'\\public\\pdfs\\User.pdf';

pdf2img.setOptions({
  type: 'png',                      // png or jpeg, default png
  size: 1024,                       // default 1024
  density: 600,                     // default 600
  outputdir:  __dirname+'\\public\\pdfs', // mandatory, outputdir must be absolute path
  targetname: 'test'                // the prefix for the generated files, optional
});

pdf2img.convert(input, function(err, info) {
  if (err) console.log(err)
  else console.log(info);
});
```

After running this i'm getting following error :

```
'identify' is not recognized as an internal or external command, 
operable program or batch file.
child_process.js:508
throw err;
^

Error: Command failed: identify -format %n C:\Users\pr326323\Pictures\samp\public\pdfs\User.pdf
'identify' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

at checkExecSyncError (child_process.js:465:13)
at execSync (child_process.js:505:13)
at async.waterfall.pages (C:\Users\pr326323\Pictures\samp\node_modules\pdf2img\lib\pdf2img.js:47:32)
at fn (C:\Users\pr326323\Pictures\samp\node_modules\pdf2img\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:638:34)
at Immediate._onImmediate (C:\Users\pr326323\Pictures\samp\node_modules\pdf2img\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:554:34)
at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:383:17)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have Ubuntu system. You also have to install Dependency for this library. Run following command:

```
sudo apt-get install graphicsmagick
```